# Maximum number of non-intersecting lines

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Given a polygon with $n$ vertices as $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_n$ and a point $A$ in 2D space, what algorithm can I use to determine how many of the segments $\overline{AP_i}$ do not intersect an edge of the polygon? That is to say, how can I determine the number of points $P_i$ which would be visible to $A$.

The following is an illustration of what I want to do:
[image]

Comment: Choose $A$ inside the polynomial. No line will intersect with the edges

Comment: I wonder whether or not it matters if the polygon is convex or not.  I'm not sure how to start approaching this but I would imagine it's much easier to answer for a convex polygon.

Comment: @Emre Not true if it's concave.

Comment: @Emre You are suggesting to change the problem statement itself

Comment: @Emre  Try to understand it in another way... A is a point outside the polygon and I want to know how many vertices of the polygon can be seen from A (line of sight)

Comment: @AmarKaswan If $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_n,A$ are all given, you can't find the maximum number of straight lines which does not intersect any side of the polygon; because it is a well-defined constant number. Maybe you should rewrite the question, and try to explain what you are asking. Maximum with respect to what?

Comment: @Jared It can be convex or concave polygon

Comment: @Emre : True (if the polygon is convex, and sometimes if it's not), but the question was about the _maximum_. $\qquad$

Comment: @all Any approximation solution?

Comment: @AmarKaswan Please tell how are we maximizing the number. Is the polygon given to us, or do we have the freedom to choose it as we wish? Is the point $A$ given to us, or do we have the freedom to choose it outside of the polygon as we want?

Comment: @Emre The given polygon is an obstacle in the path of a mobile robot or vehicle, I want to develop a graph, so that the shortest path can be  calculated while avoiding this obstacle.

Comment: @Emre Yes, everything is already given

Comment: So, this is an algorithm question to find the number of lines that intersects the polygon. The word maximum literally does not mean anything?

Comment: @Emre So we have to avoid all such lines (intersecting lines) because robot can not go through the obstacle

Comment: @Emre Yes kind of, actually I am applying DFT to solve this question and the time complexity of the DFT is O(V+E), in the case of complete graph E will be V^2 but in this scenario there will very less edges. If V are the number of vertices of the obstacle then total number of vertices will be V+2 (source and destination), In worst case,  there will be V (edges of the obstacle) + 2V edges (if we link both source and destination to all the vertices of the obstacle), so ultimately the time complexity will be O(V) only, I need to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $sgn: R \rightarrow \{-1, 0, 1\}$ be the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).
Let $P$, $Q$, $R$ = $(x_p, y_p)$, $(x_q, y_q)$, $(x_r, y_r)$.
Let $det(P, Q, R)$ be the [deretminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of matrix
$$
\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
x_p & y_p & 1 \\
x_q & y_q & 1 \\
x_r & y_r & 1 \end{array} \right|
$$
$sgn(det(P, Q, R))$ is equal to $sgn$ of sine of vectors $\vec {PR}$ and $\vec {PQ}$[image]

Therefore you can get the answer by traversing sides of polygon one by one and telling whether $P$ lies on right or left side of $A_iA_{i+1}$. This works iff the polygon is convex.

Example:
[image]
If $P$ lies on the right side of $\vec {A_iA_{i+1}}$, segment $A_iP$ does not intersect with the circumference of polygon. If $P$ is on the left, $A_iP$ does not intersect the polygon, if it lies on the right side of $\vec{A_{i-1}A_i}$

Comment: I do not get it.. Can you please do it for the given example(atleast once for both intersecting and non- intersecting lines). That would be very kind.

Comment: @AmarKaswan I edited answer

Comment: Thank you so much... But I have a doubt here, if we take A4A5 then also P is on the right side and A4P does intersect the circumference of the polygon, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Actually, since $A_4A_5$ is heading downwards, you must rotate the picture to see that $P$ is on the left.

Comment: @enerdil Thank you for your efforts! :) $P_1(0,0)$ , $P_2(2,0)$ $P_3(2,2)$ $P_4(0,2)$  are the coordinates of the given polygon and $A(3,1)$.Kindly provide solution to this problem (for every pair of of points i.e. $P_1P_2$, $P_2P_3$, $P_3P_4$ and $P_4P_1$). I am not so good at maths. It will clear all my doubts. If possible please give an algorithm(step by step) so I would be able to solve it for any scenario .Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Yep, you're right. Notice, that $A$ should be either on the right of $\vec{P_iP_{i+1}}$ or both on the left of $\vec{P_iP_{i+1}}$ and on the right of $\vec{P_{i-1}P_i}$.

Comment: Alright I got most of it. But I have two more questions, first one is we have to consider the coordinates of polygon in anticlockwise direction! Right?(if we are doing as you said to check the position of A with respect to the segment) Second one is if we do vice versa of it then we have to consider coordinates of polygon in clockwise direction?

Comment: Also tell me about the conditions to check whether A is on the right side of the segment or left side of the segment?

Comment: I guess we have to check for both anticlockwise and clockwise directions. Because A can be anywhere on the plan!

Comment: 1) You're right, however it could be made as an assumption that points of polygon are anti-clockwise oriented.

Comment: 2) That's explained on this photo. When $det(p,q,r)>0$, r is on the left, when it's greater, it is on the right.

Comment: In fact, all what matters is the order of vertices. This can be checked by telling on which side of $\vec{A_1A_2}$ is $A_3$